# Wowza GoCoder live streaming not working with audio enabled

Tags: ios, live-streaming, wowza

I'm using the `Wowza GoCoder` SDK version: `1.5.1.949` for my iOS app.

The video is being live streamed to `Wowza Streaming Engine` which is set up on my server.

Below is the code how I configure the components as given in sample apps.

```
self.goCoder = [WowzaGoCoder sharedInstance];

    // Specify the view in which to display the camera preview
    if (self.goCoder != nil) {

        // Request camera and microphone permissions
        [WowzaGoCoder requestPermissionForType:WowzaGoCoderPermissionTypeCamera response:^(WowzaGoCoderCapturePermission permission) {
            NSLog(@"Camera permission is: %@", permission == WowzaGoCoderCapturePermissionAuthorized ? @"authorized" : @"denied");
        }];

        [WowzaGoCoder requestPermissionForType:WowzaGoCoderPermissionTypeMicrophone response:^(WowzaGoCoderCapturePermission permission) {
            NSLog(@"Microphone permission is: %@", permission == WowzaGoCoderCapturePermissionAuthorized ? @"authorized" : @"denied");
        }];

        [self.goCoder registerVideoEncoderSink:self];

        self.goCoderConfig.videoEnabled = YES;
        self.goCoderConfig.audioEnabled = YES;

        self.goCoderConfig.backgroundBroadcastEnabled = TRUE;

        self.goCoder.config = self.goCoderConfig;

        self.goCoder.cameraView = self.view;

        // Start the camera preview
        self.goCoderCameraPreview = self.goCoder.cameraPreview;
        [self.goCoderCameraPreview startPreview];

    }
```

The problem occurs when I enable the audio by calling

```
self.goCoderConfig.audioEnabled = YES;
```

If I set this to false, the streaming works fine without the audio.

On `WowzaStatusCallback's onWOWZError` method I'm getting below error:

```
Error Domain=com.wowza.gocoder.sdk Code=15 "An error occurred when trying to connect to host: XXX.XXX.XX.XXX" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=An error occurred when trying to connect to host: XXX.XXX.XX.XXX}.
```

Audio streaming works fine on the Android app with no extra configuration.

Below is the log of the device before the broadcasting is stopped.

```
2018-08-07 09:55:35.658 appname[1282:305177] WowzaGoCoderSDK: Could not enable metering
2018-08-07 09:55:35.659 appname[1282:305177] WowzaGoCoderSDK: Could not set audio bit rate to target of &d
2018-08-07 09:55:35.661 appname[1282:305177] WowzaGoCoderSDK: Couldn't get queue's maximum output packet size
2018-08-07 09:55:35.662 appname[1282:305177] WowzaGoCoderSDK: AudioQueueAllocateBuffer failed
2018-08-07 09:55:35.663 appname[1282:305177] WowzaGoCoderSDK: ERROR: the PCM encoder could not be started with the specified audio settings
```

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong or what can be done to troubleshoot the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try   `self.goCoderConfig.videoEnabled = YES;
        self.goCoderConfig.audioEnabled = YES;` outside this if block.

Comment: Already tried. Seems that there is some problem with the Go Coder SDK. Raised a ticket to Wowza and they acknowledged that the problem is there but no resolution yet.

Comment: Which Version of Wowza you are using ? because I am doing the same thing , but it works fine for me.I am using wowza sdk version 1.5.1

Comment: @ZabihUllah

I have black screen issue with Wowza go coder (swift 4.2)->

We are not able to see the video of the live user only audio is audible. We tried to play the stream on different players like AVPlayer, Exoplayer (in android), even we have run the same stream on the Wowza test player still we are getting audio-only no video is visible.

We are using the HLS streaming protocol and Wowza streaming engine to play the live stream.

Please suggest us, how can we resolve this issue.